# C# property not working

Tags: asp.net, properties

Dont understand why its not working.. im using the property to set the Activelogin to true then getting the value in another page to certify that the user is has access.

```
    namespace Ibrax_1
{
    public partial class loginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public bool activelogin;          

        public bool Activelogin
        {
            get
            {
                return activelogin;
            }
            set
            {
                activelogin = value;
            }
        }
.
.
.
  Activelogin = true; // here in a method im setting the value to true.
```

and im getting value here:

```
namespace Ibrax_1
{
    public partial class Program : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAvailablePrograms();
        }

        private void CheckAvailablePrograms()
        {
            loginPage lp = new loginPage();      

            if (lp.Activelogin) //here im getting the value but its false
            {
```

am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Save your ActiveLogin in Session. (`Session["ActiveLogin"]`)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new instance:

```
loginPage lp = new loginPage();
```

That new instance will have every property set to its default value. For boolean, that's `false`.

If you're setting it to `true` somewhere else, then it won't matter since you're not looking at that instance.

It's like drawing on a piece of paper and then taking another paper and wondering why there's no drawing on it. You can't expect there to be a drawing unless you're looking at the same piece of paper.

So you need to save the instance of object somewhere so you can use it again in the `CheckAvailablePrograms` method. As Alex Kudryashev mentioned, you could save it as a `Session` variable, although it's not the only way. You can read more about the `Session` object here if you wish: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx